# Conditional fields based on another field

Tags: ms-access, conditional-statements

I am learning a bit of Microsoft Access and am trying to figure out the best way to implement a conditional in a database field.

I have a fields that designates an employee hours for the year January - December. I also have a field that is a checkbox if the employee has termed Y/N and another field that tells me which month the employee has termed.

I want the Employee Hours Jan - Dec be a conditional of if the employee has termed and when they have termed.

Ex: I have an employee John Doe that worked from Jan to Apr. I have him terminated on Apr and I want the future months to be conditionally set to 0 based on the Termed Month.

```
Unique ID | Employee | Termed | Term Month | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul |....Dec |

001        John Doe     Y           Apr      100    90    50    100   0     0     0       0
```

Comment: That is actual table structure? Can't do this in table, not if you want the field to be editable. Are you saying there would be data other than 0 in May field and you want to vacate it?

Comment: too broad of a question, but in short you want to create forms (use the wizards to get a start) so you have a user friendly interface rather than editing the unfriendly tables directly.  On a form add a button (the termination button of course) and in the button click event trigger a pop up (msgbox) to confirm and set a termination date.  Then use that info to set up a loop from the termination month to the end of the year.  Insert 0 at each month.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into using the form and making a loop!